# Add Xarray DataArray values as dimension to another DataArray

Tags: python-xarray

I'm trying to complete an analysis using `xarray.DataArray.polyfit` starting with two DataArrays, both with dimensions `x`, `y`, and `time`. What I want to do is replace the time dimension with unique values of the first array and the matching values of the second array.

So, starting with something like this:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

temperature = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.rand(5,5,30),
    coords=dict(x=range(5), y=range(5), time=range(30)),
    dims=('x','y','time')
)

size = xr.DataArray(
    np.random.rand(5,5,30),
    coords=dict(x=range(5), y=range(5), time=range(30)),
    dims=('x','y','time')
)
```

I want to create a single DataArray with dimensions `x`, `y`, and `temperature` where the temperature dimension would be unique values of temperature (and time would be dropped). Then I could run e.g.`new_array.polyfit('temperature', deg=1)` and get, for each x/y value, regression coefficients for temperature vs size.

That is, it would look like the result of

```py
new_array = xr.DataArray(
    <reshaped version of size that is 5 x 5 x number of unique values of temperature>,
    coords=dict(x=range(5), y=range(5), temperature=<unique values of temperature>),
    dims=('x','y','temperature')
)
```

I've tried several things. The closest I've gotten is probably `size.expand_dims({"temperature": temperature})` but that doesn't work with >1-dimensional DataArrays.

EDIT:
I've considered there may be a lot of unique values of temperature. I could also see binning the values before creating that dimension.

Answer (score 0):

The context here is important, as the goal is to use `.polyfit`. One way may be to use `.curvefit` instead, which allows using a DataArray as coordinates. So for a 1-d polynomial (linear) fit, we could do

```py
def lr(x, m, b):
  return m * x + b

fit = temperature.fit(size, func=lr, reduce_dims="time")
```

However I'm guessing that since this is a generic optimization that it is slower than polyfit.